# How to make window always on top in SFML?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, sfml

I am trying to make a program with SFML who's window stays always on top. How can I achieve that with SFML? I've searched all around but to no avail.

"Program" is a small red dot in the middle of a screen that would imitate a crosshair and I need it to be on top of everything because a real game would be in the background (game does not have crosshair, only sighting).

Only other idea I have, is to use SFML's method `getSystemHandle()` which would give me OS-specific handle of a window. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with Gnome and X and I am not quite sure how to code that functionality after I obtain the handle.

Comment: "What if two programs both tried to do this?" ((C) Raymond Chen)

Comment: @MSalters then we have a problem :D. But this is not for a real-world application, this is only for myself, to have some fun and to learn something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with the current version of SFML, but since you only need it  for X so far, you can just implement it yourself using a [snippet from this old/rejected pull request](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/pull/493/files#diff-fa317eaa9add8efac784c71bffc5a2ae).

```
void WindowImplX11::setTopmost(bool topmost)
{
    static Atom wmStateAbove = XInternAtom(m_display, "_NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE", 1);
    static Atom wmNetWmState = XInternAtom(m_display, "_NET_WM_STATE", 1);

    if (wmStateAbove)
    {
        XClientMessageEvent emsg;
        memset(&emsg, 0, sizeof(emsg));
        emsg.type = ClientMessage;
        emsg.window = m_window;
        emsg.message_type = wmNetWmState;
        emsg.format = 32;
        emsg.data.l[0] = topmost;
        emsg.data.l[1] = wmStateAbove;
        XSendEvent(m_display, RootWindow(m_display, m_screen), false, SubstructureRedirectMask | SubstructureNotifyMask, (XEvent*)&emsg);
    }
}
```

You'll have to retrieve `m_display`, `m_window` etc. on your own and/or reimplement the pull request into your source version.

Comment: I managed to do it, based on that code. Thank you very much. Just a note to someone who tries to use this code, I had to add `XFlush(display)` after a call to `set_always_on_top(true)` (that's how I renamed this function `setTopmost()`) for this to work because output buffer is not automatically flushed since I am not using `XNextEvent()` or similar functions that do it automatically.

Comment: Update: it works, but not for a fullscreen nor for a so called fullscreen windowed mode. Ah, well, back to the tinkering...